# como muestro imagen en php de una bd sql server

Tags: php, sql, imagen

estoy tratando de mostrar una imagen traida desde mi base de datos sql server el tipo de dato del campo es image. se supone que esta en blolb binario y para mostrarlo en mi pagina php debo convertirlo a base64 ya lo hice peero sigue sin mostrarme la imagen, en el inspecionador del navegador se puede ver la cadena convertida a base 64 en la etiqueta img, pero no me muestra

```
<?php
// Establecer conexión con la base de datos
$serverName = "localhost";
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "basedatos", "UID" => "user", "PWD" => "contraseña");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);


// Query para obtener la imagen
$query = "SELECT Content, [Mime Type] FROM [tabla] WHERE [ID] = '4C8D1272-113F-46BD-B57C-757A3C0D4CE0'";

// Ejecutar la query
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);

// Recuperar el resultado
if ($stmt && sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)) {
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    $imageData = $row['Content'];
    $mimeType = $row['Mime Type'];
    
    // Convertir el contenido de la imagen a base64
    $base64 = base64_encode($imageData);
    
    // Generar la URL de la imagen
    $src = "data:" . $mimeType . ";base64," . $base64;
   
    // Mostrar la imagen
    echo "<img src='" . $src . "' alt='Imagen'><br>";
    //echo "$imageData";
}


// Liberar recursos
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);


?>
```

Comment: podrias incluir un fragmento de como se muestra el codigo en tu navegador?

Comment: asi se ve el dato traido :

Comment: asi se ve el dato traido desde la base de datos esta es solo una parte:    'E}[��gP��6��;��^���w���RUz��C����A@�ޫHSBT������;χ�۳sΜsv��9���u��3���_�ԺP(�Ν;��ɿ5�@z�>�}"Rbbb2RR2JfjJ

JvFf'/'7������7σG�2`%UUU>q
�������N�QRP���J�<�J��������wx�4w����7

Comment: y asi cuando lo paso a base64, esta es solo una parte porque no lo puedo mandar entero :   AkV9W5S7Z1CT3xM2HBGR3juhhl6lE6oSCB2kd5AWAoQWilJVeofQQw+hiNTQQUCR3qtIUwRCFVSKCIL68vvPO8+H59uzc86cc3bn3jn3zO517d4

Answer (score 1):

El problema podría estar en:

- El tipo MIME, debe ser un tipo de imagen válido, por ejemplo `image/png` o `image/jpeg`
- Los datos binarios, antes de convertir a base64, deben ser los de una imagen válida.
- El formato de la imagen debe coincidir con el tipo MIME. Es decir, si la imagen está codificada en JPEG, el tipo MIME debe ser el correspondiente `image/jpeg` y no otro.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo que puedes correr aquí mismo en el navegador:

```html
<div>
  <p>Ejemplo tomado de la Wikpedia</p>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUA
    AAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO
        9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Punto rojo" />
</div>
```

Para depurar el problema, sugiero que hagas primero todos los pasos de manera *manual* y aislada. Es decir, toma un archivo de imagen, utiliza algún sitio en línea para convertirlo a base64 y arma un pequeño HTML con esta imagen. Cuándo logres verla bien, almacena exactamente esa imagen en tu base de datos, con el tipo MIME adecuado.

Ajusta tu código para que genere una página sencilla idéntica a la que preparaste *a mano*, solo con la imagen.

Ahora invoca el script para que se ejecute tu código y devuelva su resultado.

Si la imagen no se ve, tendrás el ejemplo que hiciste a mano con el que podrás comparar la salida del script. Dado que has utilizado exactamente la misma imagen, incluso el codificado en base64 debe ser idéntico. De esta manera el problema *saltará a la vista* y será, a partir de allí, relativamente sencillo de resolver.

Como sugerencia, puedes libremente usar la misma imagen que he colocado yo en este ejemplo para comenzar.

Un saludo.